# Style ActionBarDrawerToggle programmatically

Tags: android, actionbardrawertoggle

I started using ActionBarDrawerToggle to animate my navigation icon but have encountered a problem where I need to style the icon dynamically. Is there a way to do it programmatically?

I can style it with themes but that can't be done dynamically. I don't see any public method which would expose anything what can be styled. Thank you for your help.